# Generate all possible halves of a set (without repetition)

Tags: python, combinations

Starting with a list/set with an even number of elements, how can I generate all possible splits in equal halves where the order of the halves isn't important? For instance, {1,2,3,4} should yield:

```
{1, 2} {3, 4}
{1, 3} {2, 4}
{1, 4} {2, 3}
```

Using itertools.combinations() to generate the first half and then subtracting that from the input to get the second half generates duplicates:

```
{1, 2} {3, 4}
{1, 3} {2, 4}
{1, 4} {2, 3}
{2, 3} {1, 4}
{2, 4} {1, 3}
{3, 4} {1, 2}
```

Using inputs of less trivial size would make it very impractical to keep a list of everything that has been generated so far...

Comment: Thinking about it, your pairs of halfsets will always include one halfset with `1` and its counterpart without `1`: so from a set of size 2*n, just remove `1`, generate subsets of size n-1 and complete the work.

Comment: Remove one item which always has to be in the first set of the results and create combinations with `len/2 - 1` items.

Comment: Thanks to both, I was coming to the same conclusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pairs of halfsets will always include one halfset with some specific element and its counterpart without this element: so from a set of size 2*n, just remove this element, generate subsets of size n-1 and complete the work:

```
from itertools import combinations

n = 2
part_set = set(range(1, 2*n))
subsets = combinations(part_set, r=n-1)
for subset in subsets:
    print(({0} | set(subset), part_set - set(subset)))

# ({0, 1}, {2, 3})
# ({0, 2}, {1, 3})
# ({0, 3}, {1, 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define some rule for comparing subsets, for example compare by minimal element and agrue that `{1, 2} < {3, 4} == True` and `{3, 4} < {1, 2} == False`, and eliminate half of the splits using that rule.

```py
import itertools

def half_splits(items):
    for cmb1 in itertools.combinations(items, len(items) // 2):
        cmb1 = set(cmb1)
        cmb2 = items - cmb1
        if min(cmb1) < min(cmb2):
            yield cmb1, cmb2

for items1, items2 in half_splits({1,2,3,4}):
    print(items1, items2)
```